# An invisible border of pdfptable

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText library for generating pdf files in Java. I am writing data in pdfptable , how can I make the borders of table invisible?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The Border Elements of the PdfPTable are defined by the PdfPCell which are added to the table. Each Cell will have its own style/formatting.
Here is the API: http://api.itextpdf.com/

Example

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cellOne = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello"));
PdfPCell cellTwo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("World"));

cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cellOne.setBackgroundColor(new Color(255,255,45));

cellTwo.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);

table.addCell(cellOne);
table.addCell(cellTwo);
```

If you want more detail about the Rectangle/Border values, take a look at the IText Constant values section for Rectangle, here : http://api.itextpdf.com/constant-values.html

Comment: I tried both independently and both seem to make the border invisible. What exactly is the difference between `cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);` and `cellTwo.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);`?

Answer (score 19):

In my app it works like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);
...
```

Comment: `Rectangle.NO_BORDER` is the same as `0` I'd prefer to use the constants name, easier to read and always compatible when upgrading in version.

Comment: This method does not appear to work in version 5.5.6. Sean's answer is correct: cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

Answer (score 6):

The below works for me.

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(0f);
```

Comment: If ItextSharp 5+ ; table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0f works for the default cells only.

Comment: thnx , its working good

Answer (score 2):

For **iText 7**

```
Table table = new Table();
table.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
```

Comment: This will _not_ work. 

"Borders are defined at the level of the cell, not at the level of the table. Hence if you want to remove the borders of the table, you need to remove the borders of each cell". https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-draw-a-borderless-table-in-itextsharp

Comment: You can define at table and cell

Comment: Technically you can for some reason, but it has no effect. At least in Itext7.

Answer (score 1):

```
    PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable();
    nestedTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

    nestedTable.AddCell(new Phrase("First");
    nestedTable.AddCell(new Phrase("Second");
    nestedTable.AddCell(new Phrase("2515");

    PdfPCell nestCell= new PdfPCell(nestedTable);
```

Comment: `nestedTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;` - that just doesn't look right. Upon testing i also found that doesn't work. Unless the DefaultCell and Border properties are public this could never work.

Comment: It could work - but only in C# (seeing the case of Properties and Method calls), while OP asked about Java solution. Also, there are parenthesis missing in lines 4-6.

Answer (score 1):

set cell color white.

```
cellOne.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

***you can hide the border like this***

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell ();
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```