# Cannot hide border of iText PDF Cell while putting a sub table into one parent PDFPCell

Tags: spring, itext, itextpdf

I am using itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable for creating tables in PDF.
But I cannot get rid of border of one pdfPcell. I have searched almost everywhere, but didn't get a solution.
I can implement no border while i am using only below code-

```
    PdfPTable table_body = new PdfPTable(9);

    PdfPCell body_cell = new PdfPCell();
    body_cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);


    PdfPCell body_cell = new PdfPCell();

    body_cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("Okey woth no border implementation"));
    table_body.addCell(body_cell);
```

But the issue is occurring while i am trying to put two rows in a single PdfPcell. What i am doing to achieve this, is i am creating another table and putting it to the parent table PDFPcell. But, the issue is one border is coming every time over the are of the parent table pdfPcell though i have defined PDFPcell to be without any border.

```
           body_cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("NOT Okey woth no border implementation"));

           PdfPTable sub_table = new PdfPTable(1);

           sub_table.addCell(body_cell);
           sub_table.addCell(body_cell);
           table_body.addCell(sub_table);
```

### Added comment and code snippet below for further reference

Sorry.. But it is not working. I have tried trhis before. don't know if i am missing something. I have set defult border to no border and also at PDFCell level, i have set the border to none. Still getting a four side border around the sub table.
Here is the code snippet:

```
PdfPTable sub_table = new PdfPTable(1);
sub_table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

body_cell = new PdfPCell(image, true);
body_cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
sub_table.addCell(body_cell);
sub_table.addCell(body_cell_bottomBorder);
table_body.addCell(sub_table);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [An invisible border of pdfptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900514/an-invisible-border-of-pdfptable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `table_body.AddCell(sub_table)` you are not explicitly creating a new cell but instead are leaving the defaults up to the system which is to have a border. You need to set the default cell's border to none if you want this to work.

```
table_body.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Comment: Sorry.. But it is not working. I have tried trhis before. don't know if i am missing something. I have set defult border to no border and also at PDFCell level, i have set the border to none. Still getting a four side border around the sub table.
Here is the code snippet:

PdfPTable sub_table = new PdfPTable(1);
sub_table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    
body_cell = new PdfPCell(image, true);
body_cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
sub_table.addCell(body_cell);
sub_table.addCell(body_cell_bottomBorder);
table_body.addCell(sub_table);

Comment: You need to set the `NO_BORDER` on the outer table, in this case `table_body`

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. that solved my issue. But i would request you to look at one more problem though it also may be a silly mistake again i am making. I have updated the question with the new problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Ani, this really would be better suited as a second question. Can you undo your edit and post another question?

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your help. I have put the new question in a different thread.I request you to have a look. thanks again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155155/bottomborder-for-the-subtable-cell-and-for-the-general-pdfpcell-of-parent-table